# Lambda check for null

Tags: asp.net, lambda, null

```
var pq = attributes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AttributeName == PasswordQuestion").AttributeValue;
```

The above code will throw an error if null. What is the best way to handle this?
The below code would work, but I can't help but feel there's a more graceful way?

```
var pq = (attributes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AttributeName == "PasswordQuestion") != null) ? attributes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AttributeName == "PasswordQuestion").AttributeValue : null;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually leverage the `Select` method for things like this:

```
var pq = attributes.Where(a => a.AttributeName == "PasswordQuestion")
            .Select(a => a.AttributeValue)
            .SingleOrDefault();
```